# Why does the package upi_pay fails to do the transactions?

Tags: flutter, upi

I have tried to do the transaction between two UPI id (both was normal account, that is, not a merchant account).

I have tried to do the transaction with Phonepay, but Phone pay says,
`For security reasons, you are not allowed to send money from your bank for this payment.`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to check this:

> Several major payment apps are looking to avoid fraud on UPI by doing
> a strict check on the authenticity of payments. This makes these issues
> appear more related to the lack of merchant signature in the current
> version of the package. This is further seen in the following snippet
> from the [UPI deep linking specification](https://github.com/reeteshranjan/upi_pay/files/6338127/UPI.Linking.Specs_ver.1.6.pdf) which is about how a UPI
> payment app should verify a UPI deep linking request (the ones made
> through this package)

You can find more details on this issue or similar issues [here](https://github.com/drenther/upi_pay/issues/38)